# React - Firebase, Detect Profile data update to reload a component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to display a name if display name is available otherwise, I'm displaying a form to enter name.

```
{
    currentUser?.displayName != null ?
        <WelcomeMessage user={currentUser} />
        :
        <ProfileUpdate user={currentUser} />
}
```

I have an auth provider on the higher level and am using a useAuth hook ( following this https://usehooks.com/useAuth/ )

for the submit handler, I'm doing this

```js
const submitHandler: SubmitHandler<TProfileData> = (data) => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            user.updateProfile({
                displayName: data.displayName
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
```

I would like to evaluate the first section after updating the displayName.